# ¿Abrir el mismo formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quiero abrir el mismo formulario, sin tener que abrir varios más  al dar click sobre mi `toolStripMenuItem2` o cualquier otro botón tengo mi siguiente código:`

```
private void notasDeEntradaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmcontrol log = new frmcontrol();
        log.MdiParent = this;
        log.Show();
    }
```

No quiero usar el `ShowDialog` pues se que únicamente me abrirá el `frmcontrol` pero no me dejara realizar las demás tareas.
(solo quiero mostrar el mismo form que ya está abierto) espero me puedan ayudar o me comprendan.

Comment: DIces que quieres abrir el mismo pero luego dices que *solo quieres mostrar el mismo form que ya esta abierto*. Puedes ser mas especifico en lo que buscas? \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar abrir dos veces el mismo formulario, podrías verificar esto haciendo uso de la propiedad [OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) que representa una colección de los formularios de su aplicación , podría verificar el indice cuyo valor será nombre del formulario , si es diferente de `null` , solo activamos dicho formulario , caso contrario lo mostramos con `show()`

```
 if (Application.OpenForms["frmcontrol"] != null)
 {
    Application.OpenForms["frmcontrol"].Activate();
 }
 else
 {
   frmcontrol form = new frmcontrol();
   form.MdiParent = this;
   form.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Parece una buena idea. Creo que lo único que faltaría es de asignar el string `"frmcontrol"` a la propiedad `Name`, de lo contrario creo que queda vacío, de modo que nunca lo vas a encontrar en el `Application.OpenForms`: `form.Name = "frmcontrol";`

Comment: Muchas gracias, tenia la idea de usar un if, pero no encontraba la manera.